# Set variable in if statement expression

Tags: php, if-statement

I ran across some interesting code today. I tried to find out if this is a feature of PHP or if I am missing something, but was unable to find anything on Google. Probably because I don't know the name of it.

**Code**

```
if($logo = \Repositories\Logo::getLogoData($id)){
     $logo_href = $logo->link;
}
```

The variable `$logo` is not being set anywhere else. It seems like the expression in this if statement is checking to see if the that class method is returning anything and simultaneously setting the variable `$logo` to be used in the statement.

Is this true? If so, what in the world is this called!?!

Comment: first it assigns, then evaluates the return value of the assignment which is the assigned result.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can make an assignment like that in a conditional. What happened logically is that the value is assigned to `$logo` and then `$logo` is evaluated as to whether it is truthy. If it is truthy, the code in the conditional executes.

You will oftentimes see this sort of assignment/evaluation in the case of looping through database result sets, but generally I would suggest that it should be avoided outside such a common use case for sake of clarity in reading g code.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I can't seem to find any official documentation on it. Is there a name for it? I want to read the docs about it.

Comment: @ChrisB: It's just how the assignment operator works.  It returns the assigned value.  Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: @RocketHazmat I guess I just didn't know you could do that inside of an if statement's expression

Comment: @ChrisB: The `=` is just an operator, like `+` or `*`.  It can be used it lots of places :-)

Comment: @ChrisB Generally, use of the assignment operator in a conditional like this should be frowned upon (IMO at least).  There are however the handful of cases like looping through a result set of unknown length where it makes sense for example something like: `while($row = $db_result->fetch(){ ... }`. But in this case my preference would have been to put the assignment on a separate line of code before the conditional. I think this code is more readable and less error prone that way.

Comment: Can you please describe what the scope is of the assigned variable? Can you reference it outside the `if` block?

Comment: @KolobCanyon PHP is not block-level-scoped so this variable is available before, during, and after a conditional such as this within whatever it's enclosing scope is (global or function/method level).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a feature. It's like:

`$a=$b=5;`

But in this case, imagine the bool result of if as var $a.

However, IDE's are used to complain about solutions like this because of == vs. = as a very common possible bug source.