# Assign and use variable inside of PHP if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am wondering whether it is possible to use a variable inside of the same `if` statement that it is assigned in using PHP.

For example:

```
if ($start = strtotime($_POST['date']) && $start <= time()) {
    $error = 'You must choose a date in the future.';
}
```

That code does not appear to be working for me, but I don't see why it shouldn't since I know the variable can be assigned like that, and it would make sense for me for the following variable to then be able to access it.

Comment: Answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092730/set-variable-in-if-statement-expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set variable in if statement expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092730/set-variable-in-if-statement-expression)

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @JDSchenck that thread does not address whether or not I can use the assigned variable in the same statement

Comment: @Barmer, when i post a date in the future, the statement returns "You must choose...". Please see https://eval.in/955103.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running into operator precedence problems. `&&` has higher precedence than `=`, so it's being processed as:

```
if ($start = (strtotime($_POST['date']) && $start <= time())) {
```

This doesn't assign to `$start` until after the `&&` expression completes, which means it will try to use `$start` in the comparison before it has been assigned. And it also assigns a boolean `true/false` value to `$start`, which is obviously not useful.

Either put parentheses around the assignment, or use the lower precedence `and` operator:

```
if (($start = strtotime($_POST['date'])) && $start <= time()) {

if ($start = strtotime($_POST['date']) and $start <= time()) {
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie This answer addressed the problem exactly. The problem was the higher order of `&&`, if you want to see an example of the problem, see here: https://eval.in/955110.